# Is it possible/smart to write a lazy loading macro implementor?

Tags: objective-c, macros

My code (especially as I get more into [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)) has lots of lazily-loaded properties, like:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyFoo *myFoo;

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (MyFoo *)myFoo {
   if (!_myFoo) {
     _myFoo = [MyFoo alloc] sharedFoo]; // or initWithBar:CONST_DEF_BAR or whatever
   }
   return _myFoo;
}

@end
```

Or, better, thread-safe version:

```
- (MyFoo *)myFoo {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _storeHelper = [SHStoreHelper sharedStoreHelper];
  });
}
```

I kind of wish Apple would just make that an aspect of a property eligible for automatic code generation, like:

```
@property (lazyload) MyFoo *myFoo;
```

Barring that, though, I would like to have a macro for the implementation bit, something like

```
#define LAZY_ALLOC(x, y, _y, a, i) -(x *)y { if (!_y) { _y = [[x a] i]; } return _y }
```

and then instead of the regular method implementation you just have

```
LAZY_ALLOC(MyClass, myClass, _myClass, alloc, init)
```

which is flexible enough for classes that want

```
LAZY_ALLOC(OtherClass, otherClass, _otherClass, sharedClass, nil)
```

or

```
LAZY_ALLOC(OtherClass, otherClass, _otherClass, alloc, initWithFrame:SOME_FRAME)
```

1) The preprocessor requires _y. Is there a way to make it construct the _autosynthesized ivar without passing it in separately?
2) Are there big problems with this? For me it enhances readability because it in essence says "oh that thing again" more quickly than the fully-written-out version
3) Do you think it's icky stylistically? Awesome stylistically?

Comment: It's a hack. (And unrelated to Xcode...)

Comment: FWIW your implementation is not thread-safe.  Consider using [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) for thread safety, although even that is not trivial to get right.

Comment: Ooh, good point. See edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is `##`. You could write it as:

```
#define LAZY_ALLOC(type, name, initialValue) \
    -(type *)name { \
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken; \
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{ \
            if (! _ ## name) { \
                _ ## name = (initialValue); \
            } \
        } \
        return _ ## name; \
    }
```

#### EDIT:

To be clear, I would not use this particular idiom for lazy loading outside of a singleton's `sharedInstance`-type method. This code will only do the lazy loading once *per class* (not per instance) because of the static dispatch_once_t. I just copied the code out of the question and converted it to a macro template to illustrate that technique, but I feel like I should clarify this.

Personally, for lazy loading normal instance variables, I would go with the non-thread-safe version and just switch to eager loading or handle the case specially if you need thread-safety. There are techniques for combining lazy loading with thread safety in accessors, but:

1. They are fairly slow.
2. It's rare to really need both at once.
3. You're probably going to have to do some special architecting for thread-safety anyway beyond just sticking mutexes in your accessor methods.

so I wouldn't incorporate that case into a standard template macro.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method `+(id) lazyLoad:(Class)class sharedPointer:(NSObject**)ptrAddr` or some such.  Make it a method of the LazyLoader class, which only implements this method.

To use it:

```
- (MyFoo *)myFoo {
    return [LazyLoader lazyLoad:[MyFoo class] sharedPointer:&_myFoo];
}
```

Probably needs some ARC sweeteners on the sharedPointer parm, but basically that should work, and can be made as thread-safe as you may wish (if you wish).

(I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out how to do alternate init methods.)

Comment: Hmm, that seems like nearly as much typing as just writing out teh codez in full... :) The real draw for me was to be able to just put all my property lazy-methods together, each on a line.

Comment: You could probably macro-ize it a bit to make it smaller.  All you need is the class name and the shared pointer name.  Could even macro-ize the procedure header if you wished.